# How to Remove Parent Page Link from WordPress Submenus with Three or More Nested Levels?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I'm encountering an issue with WordPress menus where if there are three or more nested submenus, WordPress automatically includes the parent page link followed by the submenu link.

[image: Menu having 3 nested sub menu]

For example, in the above case, the "service" menu has three submenu items:

Brand strategy
Website Design
Digital Marketing
And each of these submenu items may have further submenus.

When clicking on any submenu item like "Website Design," WordPress generates the default URL structure as follows:

Default URL is. : xyz.com/services/website-design 
URL that I want : xyz.com/website-design

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: The URL is determined by the page hierarchy. You can restructure the pages by setting and unsetting the parent pages in the page attributes settings.

Comment: Yes. But I want the same hierarchy. But not want parent page in url

Comment: The page hierarchy and the structure of the menu are seperate from each other. Though the menu looks at the page hierarchy, it does allow you to create a different hierarchy for the menu's.

Comment: Thre is no parent hierarchy set at page level